# SQL Server : optimize query with many 'and like' statements

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Let's say you have the query:

```
select columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD
from tableA
where columnA like '%hello%' and columnB like '%error%';
```

What's a good way to index a table for multiple and like conditions?

Do you need an index with both columnA and columnB pointing to columnC and columnD

or

do you need columnA pointing to B, C, D and columnB pointing to A, C, D.

I'm unsure which would be more helpful to the optimizer here....

Comment: An index on those columns will be mostly (if not completely) pointless if you want to use those filter conditions

Comment: No indexing is going to help here because you have leading wildcards.

Comment: Darn, so would it be possible to do something like, say, find the results matching the first like condition, store a tmp table, then use the second like condition to filter from those results? Would that possibly help at all?

Comment: Is it possible to do that?, of course. Would that help?, probably not

Answer (score 0):

Full-text search (FTS) can help, but be aware that it has a lot of caveats, a rather steep learning curve and a significant maintenance and administration overhead.

And no, it will not help you with searching for an arbitrary substring within the word, either. That is, `hello` as a separate word (or as a beginning of one) will be found, but `*ello` will not. Judging by your examples, however, this shouldn't be an issue.